# Arch Linux doesn't boot

Tags: arch-linux

When I turn on my pc, instead of booting Arch, it just takes me to the bios and in order to boot it I have to go to "boot from file" and select: NO VOLUME LABEL, [PciRoot(0x10, 0x0)/HD(1,GPT1D1806B-E2BB-3846-A25E-F86C6D0F5971, 0x800, 0x100000)] then EFI then BOOT and then BOOTX64.EFI. How can I make it boot directly to arch?

The output of lsblk is:

```
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0      179:0    0  28.9G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0   512M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0    20G  0 part /
└─mmcblk0p3  179:3    0   8.4G  0 part /home
mmcblk0boot0 179:8    0     4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:16   0     4M  1 disk 
mmcblk2      179:24   0 119.1G  0 disk 
└─mmcblk2p1  179:25   0 119.1G  0 part
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a boot partition.*

Create a new partition and mount it to `/boot` or `/efi` (it doesn't really matter), you then need to format it to FAT32 because that's the EFI requirement. Refer to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide#Partition_the_disks) part of arch wiki installation guide.

Then make sure you have `grub` installed and set up the boot partition with it. Reference [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems)

*It looks like `mmcblk0p1` should be the boot partition, so make sure it's mounted and formated properly, then maybe try booting up your system, and see if grub is already set up on it, if not refer to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems)